# ошибка импорта в django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

в файл url.py пробую импортировать settings.py из одного и того же каталога , выдает ошибку : ModuleNotFoundError

```
# так мне vscod подсказывает
from learnsite.learnsite import settings

# так я пробовал 
import settings
```

в обоих случаях выглядит все нормально , пока я не запускаю сервер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код ошибки :

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/taurus/news_projects/Django_study/learnsite/learnsite/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    import settings 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный способ импортировать настройки в django:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

PS: возможно, вам будет интересно почитать о [различии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780756/is-there-any-difference-between-django-conf-settings-and-import-settings)

Comment: спасибо ,работает. правда интерпритатор странно выделяет